# npm start command not working for my react app

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing

I am trying to start my `react` app on `localhost:3000`, but when I do `npm start` I get these error messages :
[image: Errors]

I am sure it has to do with either `npm` or my `package.json` file, but I can't put my finger on exactly what is causing the problem.

This is my `package.json` file :

[image: package.json]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the comma at the end of the `build` command in your package.json, and then run npm start.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely your `package.json` file has syntax error, I proffer to you use a better code editor or use a better configuration for your `sublime` to show your syntax error.

In the end of `line:10` you miss a comma `,`:

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=production browserify -t [ reactify --es6 ] app.js | uglifyjs > compiled.js", //<== this comma is missed
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a comma on line 10 in your `package.json`. Add it and it should be fine.